# Fullcalendar not reloading, even with refetchEvents and rerenderEvents

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I have searched stackoverflow on this topic, and have tried the solutions, but it hasn't worked for me. Even if I reload the entire page, none of the added events show up in the calendar until I kill the program and restart it. I know it's going THROUGH the code, because I've hit breakpoints on both the refetchEvents and rerenderEvents lines.

Following is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var TheCalendar = $('#ODCalendar').fullCalendar({
        header:
            {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
        buttonText: {
            today: 'today',
            month: 'month',
            week: 'week',
            day: 'day'
        },

        events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/GetCalendarData',
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "JSON",

                success: function (result) {
                    var events = [];

                    $.each(result, function (i, data) {
                        var bColor = "#000000";
                        var tColor = "#FFFFFF";
                        switch (data.ReleaseType) {
                            case '1':
                                if (data.Action == '1') {
                                    bColor = '#cc9900';
                                }
                                else if (data.Action == '2') {
                                    bColor = '#ffd24d';
                                    tColor = "#000000";
                                }
                                else {
                                    bColor = '#e6e6e6';
                                }
                                break;
                            case '2':
                                if (data.Action == '1') {
                                    bColor = '#ff8080';
                                }
                                else if (data.Action == '2') {
                                    bColor = '#ffcccc';
                                    tColor = "#000000";
                                }
                                else {
                                    bColor = '#e6e6e6';
                                }
                                break;
                            case '3':
                                if (data.Action == '1') {
                                    bColor = '#0099ff';
                                }
                                else if (data.Action == '2') {
                                    bColor = '#ccebff';
                                    tColor = "#000000";
                                }
                                else {
                                    bColor = '#e6e6e6';
                                }
                                break;
                            case '4':
                                if (data.Action == '1') {
                                    bColor = '#2fb62f';
                                }
                                else if (data.Action == '2') {
                                    bColor = '#d6f5d6';
                                    tColor = "#000000";
                                }
                                else {
                                    bColor = '#e6e6e6';
                                }
                                break;
                            case '99':
                                bColor = '#cccccc';
                                break;
                            default:
                                bColor = '#999999';
                        }

                        events.push(
                            {
                                title: data.Title,
                                description: data.Description,
                                start: moment(data.Start_Date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'),
                                end: moment(data.End_Date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'),
                                url: '/Home/ShowEditEvent?id=' + data.id + '&Owner=' + data.Owner,
                                textColor: tColor,
                                backgroundColor: bColor,
                                borderColor: "#000066"
                            });
                    });

                    callback(events);
                }
            });
        },

        eventRender: function (event, element) {
            element.qtip(
                {
                    content: event.description
                });
        },

        editable: true
    });
    // Refresh each time home page loads
    $('#ODCalendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    $('#ODCalendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
    });
```

The data is created in an MVC Controller. I use HTML.BeginForm insteadn of AJAX.BeginForm because it causes more trouble for me than it's worth:

```
public ActionResult AddEvent(Guid CalendarID = new Guid(), string Title = "",
            int Owner = 0, string Description = "", string Start_Date = "", string End_Date = "",
            string ReleaseType = "", string ReleaseVersion = "", string Action = "", string Network = "", string CRQ = "",
            string Comments = "", string StoreList = "", bool SharedEntry = true)
        {
            CalendarEntry model = new CalendarEntry();

            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CalendarConnection"].ToString()))
                {
                    string query = "Insert Into CalendarEntry (id, CalendarID, Title, Owner, Description, Start_Date, End_Date, ReleaseType, ReleaseVersion, Action, Network, CRQ, Comments, StoreList, SharedEntry)" +
                        " Values(@id, @CalendarID, @Title, @Owner, @Description, @Start_Date, @End_Date, @ReleaseType, @ReleaseVersion, @Action, @Network, @CRQ, @Comments, @StoreList, @SharedEntry)";

                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", id);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("CalendarID", CalendarID);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Title", Title);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Owner", Owner);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Description", Description);
                    //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Start_Date", Start_Date);
                    //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("End_Date", End_Date);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Start_Date", Start_DateDT);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("End_Date", End_DateDT);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ReleaseType", ReleaseType);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ReleaseVersion", ReleaseVersion);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Action", Action);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Network", Network);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("CRQ", CRQ);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Comments", Comments);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("StoreList", StoreList);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("SharedEntry", SharedEntry);
                    connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            return Redirect("Index");
        }
```

I am going back to the Index page were the Calendar resides, and it goes through the javascript code - but doesn't reload it. Where am I going wrong, please?

Comment: Thank you for editing it, Dan.

Comment: are the events definitely being added to the database? Is GetCalendarData returning the new events in its JSON? Have they got valid dates in them? I note in AddEvent for some reason you're accepting the dates as strings instead of DateTime objects, and then not validating them. I hope you're not also storing the dates as strings in your database? I notice you add your dates to the parameter list using Start_DateDT and End_DateDT...yet these are not otherwise mentioned in your code above - where do these variables come from? It looks like your C# code would not compile.

Comment: P.S. Why aren't you accepting a single "Event" ViewModel object in your AddEvent method rather than a series of individual parameters? Strong binding to a model object is one of the big advantages of MVC, and you're ignoring it...

Comment: Well, I figured out this much. It's a browser issue. Everything works fine in Chrome, but not in IE. Unfortunately, I HAVE to get it working in IE. So, I need to do a little more research. And I'll look into binding it better, ADyson.

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY found the answer. Actually, I found it two days ago, but put the line of code in the wrong place. I found the right place this time. Need just to add one line:

```
cache: false
```

in here:

```
events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/GetCalendarData',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            cache: false,

            success: function (result) {
                var events = [];
```

etc...

Thank you for your assistance.

- John C